# Bernoulli differential equation proving

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, bernoulli-numbers

As we know, the differential equation in the form is called the Bernoulli equation

$ \frac {dy}{dx} + p(x)y = q(x)y^n  $

How do i show that if $y$ is the solution of the above Bernoulli equation and $ u = y^{1-n} $, then u satisfies the linear differential equation

$ \frac{du}{dx} +(1-n)p(x)u = (1-n)q(x) $

I can use the substituion to use solve differential equations like

$y' + xy  = xy^2$

but have no idea how to prove  this question .

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Express $y$ in terms of $u$ and subsitute in the initial equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that from $u=y^{1-n}$, by the chain rule, we get
$$
\frac{du}{dx}=(1-n)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot y^{-n}\qquad \text{or} \qquad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{(1-n)}\cdot y^{n}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}
$$ then plugging it into
$$
\frac {dy}{dx} + p(x)y = q(x)y^n
$$ using $y=y^n u$ gives
$$
\frac1{(1-n)}\cdot y^{n}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}+p(x)\cdot y^n u= q(x)y^n
$$ or equivalently
$$
\frac{du}{dx} +(1-n)p(x)u = (1-n)q(x)
$$ as desired.